# sql sever practice so could help ht get this two tasks

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
Input       Out Put
Current Previous    
1001    Null    
2331    7808    -6807
2312    8965    -6634
3213    5557    -3245
8768    3453    -240
8857    6577    2191
Null    6778    2079
```

Note :  First Row - Second row in second column

```
Task 2
Input Data 
-100
0
45
124567
-1
1
75
45
-56
-89
999
-345
789
-3
```

Logic : When a value is passed to this table, closest value available in the table has to be retrieved

:for instance if 1000 is pased 999 has to retrived, if 0 is passsed 0 has to be thte out pur if -55 is passed -56 has to be the out cum

Comment: Try to edit your question, make it more clear to read and understand. And ask for a problem you have, not ask to us to do it

Comment: I think you're after something like this: `select top 1 id from mytable order by abs(id - @id)`

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 [input data]
from [task 2]
order by abs([input data] - @searchTerm)
```